# расположение элементов flex блока равноудалённо от верхней и нижней границ блока

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox, position

Приветствую

Использую `flex` для того, чтобы расположить блоки в несколько столбцов (при этом порядок блоков идет вертикально по нарастающий, как только доходят до нижней границы блока начинается новый ряд)

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы контейнер с блоками  находился по вертикали по центру блока.

Можно ли это сделать через `flex` свойства или придется использовать `padding`?

Пока единственное из очевидных решений, которые вижу - зная высоту блока `<div>` и высоту элементов `<li>` (включая `margin`) вычислить какой нужен padding для `div`, чтобы элементы `li` встали по центру, но это как-то топорно кажется :(

Если использую

```
align-content:              space-around;
```

элементы самого правого ряда (их меньше чем в остальных рядях) смещаются к центру относительно остальных элементов, а мне этого не нужно.

Вот пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/qgrue5n2/

```css
div {
    margin:                     0px;
    padding:                    0px;

    width:                      100%;
    height:                     170px;

    background:                 lime;
}

ul {
    display:                    flex;
    flex-flow:                  wrap column;
    justify-content:            flex-start;
    align-content:              flex-start;

    width:                      100%;
    height:                     100%;

    margin:                     0px;
    padding:                    0px;    

    list-style:                 none;   
}

li {
    cursor:                     pointer;    

    display:                    block;

    width:                      150px;
    height:                     25px;

    margin:                     2px;
    padding:                    0px;

    font-family:                Calibri;
    font-size:                  14px;
    font-weight:                400;

    text-transform:             uppercase;
    text-align:                 left;
    line-height:                25px;

    color:                      #000000;
    background:                 white;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>TEXT #1</li>
        <li>TEXT #2</li>
        <li>TEXT #3</li>
        <li>TEXT #4</li>
        <li>TEXT #5</li>
        <li>TEXT #6</li>
        <li>TEXT #7</li>
        <li>TEXT #8</li>
        <li>TEXT #9</li>
        <li>TEXT #10</li>
        <li>TEXT #11</li>
        <li>TEXT #12</li>
        <li>TEXT #13</li>
        <li>TEXT #14</li>
        <li>TEXT #15</li>
        <li>TEXT #16</li>
        <li>TEXT #17</li>
        <li>TEXT #18</li>
        <li>TEXT #19</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
div {
    height:170px;
    background:lime;
}
ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap; /* << тут */
    align-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
   list-style: none; 
}
li {
    cursor:pointer;    
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    height:25px;
    margin:2px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:400;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:25px;
    color:#000000;
    background:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>TEXT #1</li>
        <li>TEXT #2</li>
        <li>TEXT #3</li>
        <li>TEXT #4</li>
        <li>TEXT #5</li>
        <li>TEXT #6</li>
        <li>TEXT #7</li>
        <li>TEXT #8</li>
        <li>TEXT #9</li>
        <li>TEXT #10</li>
        <li>TEXT #11</li>
        <li>TEXT #12</li>
        <li>TEXT #13</li>
        <li>TEXT #14</li>
        <li>TEXT #15</li>
        <li>TEXT #16</li>
        <li>TEXT #17</li>
        <li>TEXT #18</li>
        <li>TEXT #19</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: KIrill, для горизонтального следования элементов все работает замечательно, но мне надо вертикальное (column) - и вот тут начинаются проблемы :(